# https POST result in different response - python(w/ requests returns 200) works well whereas Javascript(w/ axios returns 500) doesn't

Tags: javascript, json, axios, http-status-code-500

I've made a simple https POST code snippet using python and javascript.

I expected that all results will be same but the results are not.

Python result(w/ requests) returns 200 whereas javascript(w/ axios) returns 500.

I think all conditions including headers are exactly equal but I wonder why this situation happens.

Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

---

**[Python code] / python 3.9.6**

```
import requests
import json
s = requests.Session()

_url = 'https://graphql.bitquery.io/'
_data = {
        "variables": json.dumps({
        "limit": 1,
        "offset": 0,
        "network": "ethereum",
        "token": "0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52",
        "from": "2021-06-01",
        "till": "2022-01-02T23:59:59",
        "dateFormat": "%Y-%m-%d"
        })
}

r = s.post(url=_url, data=_data)
r.text
```

Its response returns 200 and the result is below.

```
'{"data":{"ethereum":{"transfers":[{"block":{"timestamp":{"time":"2022-01-02 23:59:50"},"height":13929166},"sender":{"address":"0xf60c2ea62edbfe808163751dd0d8693dcb30019c","annotation":null},"receiver":{"address":"0x7b60d1c03cda03952bebc58d7a64c2e15f738356","annotation":null},"transaction":{"hash":"0x09be49c24fc639572a6dcc4e338ce57c5f2d206c983935f6c21df522276dc875"},"amount":0.24,"currency":{"symbol":"BNB"},"external":true}]}}}'
```

I also wrote another simple snippet using javascript w/ axios and I expected the same result but...

**[Javascript code] / node.js v16.13.1**

```
const axios = require('axios')

const _url = 'https://graphql.bitquery.io/'
const _data = {
        "variables": JSON.stringify({
        "limit": 1,
        "offset": 0,
        "network": "ethereum",
        "token": "0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52",
        "from": "2021-06-01",
        "till": "2022-01-02T23:59:59",
        "dateFormat": "%Y-%m-%d"
        })
}

const r = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.post(_url, {
        data: _data
    })
    console.log(resp)
}
r()
```

Its response returns 500 and the result is below.

```
Uncaught Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

Comment: that means your js axios request is invalid. your url is fine but I think data that you are sending is in invalid format which gets rejected straight away.  you need to adjust according to config of api. for example you can stringify your entire data, not only variables. it is also possible that you may need parsers to format the request and response. in the worst case, you can use postman for your request and check nodejs axios version to see the correct syntax

Comment: 5xx error codes refer to *Internal Server Error*. Check your node logs/terminal for any errors thrown.

Comment: @NiceBooks probably not that easy to do, when it is an external API (which I would assume `graphql.bitquery.io` to be here in this context.)

Comment: I don't think passing `{ data: _data }` in your axios request is correct here, that should probably be just `data`.

Comment: @CBroe I really appreciate your help. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

@CBoe Thank you for your help.
It was due to an axios syntax mistake.

```
const r = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.post(_url, {
        data: _data
    })
    console.log(resp)
}
r()
```

-> it should be revised as below.

```
const r = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.post(_url, _data)
    console.log(resp)
}
r()
```

Its response returns 200.

```
{status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: ClientRequest, …}
```

Comment: In that case https://graphql.bitquery.io/ide has a bug. In theory, should have returned a 400 or 422 error. if there's a problem with the request body